# Unable to debug c program linux using eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I've change my IDE to Eclipse and I want to use debug with CDT. But when I click on the debug, the following error occurs:

```
Can't find a source file at "/mnt/OrtakDisk/genel/C/\303\207al\304\261\305\237malar/5.Nesil Veri Yap\304\261lar\304\261/Veri Yap\304\261lar\304\261 1/src/Veri Yap\304\261lar\304\261 1.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

Also I can't see the array's values.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of error message. All information should be included as text in your question. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your warning.I didn't know that rule because   I'm new in Stackoverflow. I made the necessary arrangements.